# Reading a value from file in C

Tags: c, binaryfiles, fseek

I wish to compare a value from a particular location in a binary file (say, value from index n x i, where i = 0,1,2,3... and n = any number, say 10).
I want to see if that value is equal to another, say "m". The location of that value in the file is always in n x i only.

I can think of three methods to this:

1. I maintain a temp variable which stores the value of n x i and I directly use fseek go to that index and see if it is equal to m.
2. I do an fseek for the value of m in the file.
3. I search for the value of m in locations 0, n, 2n, 3n,... and so on using fseek.

I don't know how each of these operations work, but which one of these is the most efficient with respect to space and time taken?

Edit:
This process is a part of a bigger process, which has many more files and hence time is important.
If there is any other way than using fseek, please do tell.

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do and the format of your data. Is this some kind of search?

Comment: Yes.
I have a value called minkey, and I want to search the location that has that value in the file and read the next 4 values from it.

Comment: By the way, why was my post downvoted? I don't have much experience using this site, so please tell me so I can work on it when I ask other questions.

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted. Maybe because it's not clear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 4):

Without any prior knowledge of the values and ordering in the file you are searching, the quickest way is just to look through the file linearly and compare values.

This might be best done by using fseek() repeatedly, but repeatedly calling fseek and read may be slower than just reading big chunks of the file and looking through them in memory - because system calls have a lot of overhead.

However if you are doing a lot of searches of the same files, you would be better off building an index and/or sorting your records. One way to do this would be put the data into a relational database with built-in indexes (pretty much any SQL database)

Edit:

Since you know your file is sorted, you can use a [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).

Comment: I forgot to add that the binary file I wish to search through is already sorted.